# Нужна ли запятая перед "тоже" в качестве уточнения?

Tags: пунктуация

Кроме вопросов, вам предстоит решить контрольные работы тоже в виде вопросов.

Comment: Решить... работы? Если это не домашнее задание, то есть смысл подправить.

Answer (score 1):

**Возможны варианты** (интонационные схемы будут разными):

(1) *Кроме вопрОсов, вам предстоит выполнить контрольные работы // тоже в виде вопрОсов.*

(2) *Кроме вопрОсов, вам предстоит выполнить // контрОльные работы, тоже в виде вопрОсов.*

**Пояснение**

Обособление оборотов с союзом ТОЖЕ **не регламентируется**  особыми правилами,  выбор зависит от структуры предложения.

При такой распространенности обособление оборота **желательно**, оборот будет иметь присоединительное значение.

При меньшей распространенности более вероятен **необособленный** вариант, например: Кроме вопрОсов, даны контрольные работы // тоже в виде вопрОсов.

**Примеры оборотов** с союзом ТОЖЕ (при обособлении может использоваться тире)

На вопрос является ответ **тоже** в виде вопроса: да русский ли он? [В. О. Ключевский. Русская история (1904)]

Приведу здесь, **тоже** в виде примера оригинальности, взгляд одного англичанина на свою веру, протестантизм. [Ф. М. Достоевский (1876)]

Храм был тринадцатиглавым ― **тоже** для Византии явление невиданное. [С. А. Еремеева. Лекции по русскому искусству (2000)]

При входе стоят полки специально для новых изданий, **тоже** для привлечения покупателей. [Владимир Голяховский (1984-2001)]

Answer (score 0):

> Нужна ли запятая перед "тоже" в качестве уточнения?

Запятая нужна. Раз в качестве уточнения — то однозначно, так как уточнение требует либо запятую, либо тире (оно здесь тоже подходит). Хотя порой с "тоже" можно его и не делать, но здесь без него (и без паузы) звучит вообще не по-русски.